# Como ativar uma virtualenv utilizando shell-script?

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, shell-script, virtualenv

Eu preciso rodar um código em python 3.6, e criei uma virtualenv, porém não consigo ativa-lá com um arquivo .sh.
A intenção de utilização de um arquivo .sh é para agendamento no crontab.

Forma que tentei:

```
#!/bin/bash
source /home/opt/.virtualenvs/sensorP36/bin/activate
```

Alguém sabe como posso resolver isso?